# Is it possible to work with the database using only the built-in features of node.js?

Tags: javascript

I am doing a test task for the position of a junior react developer, and the employer requires me to write the server part (node.js + postgres) using only the built-in features of node.js?... Without npm packages and libraries at all. I have to connect to a database and work with it. Is it even possible? There is nothing helpful in the node.js documentation. It seems that node.js does not provide the ability to interact with databases at all without external npm packages and libraries. I spent a whole day searching for information, but found nothing. I would be glad if someone could give me some advice.

Comment: There are libraries written in pure js that do that so it's possible

Comment: Most Npm packages are just some external code that does something (interacts with the databases in your case) using built-in features of Node.js (and maybe other Npm packages).

Comment: This library has no dependencies, you can check the source code to 
learn how to create connection etc https://github.com/porsager/postgres

Comment: I just want to say that this doesn't sound like a reasonable recruitment task. I doubt anyone can do it in less than a week in their free time. Also, it doesn't make any sense to give task like that to a junior frontend developer.

Comment: I'm not the only one who thinks this is incorrect. This makes me happy. Thank you so much!